# How can I learn to use Oracle DB with PHP?

Tags: php, oracle

I would like to learn to use Oracle some, just for the sake of learning it.  Is there a way to do this without spending a lot of money?  I looked on the oracle site and the cheapest thing I saw was this...

**Oracle Database Personal Edition**
Oracle Database Personal Edition is designed to provide software developers a cost effective, yet full featured Oracle Database environment on which to develop, test and run custom or packaged applications. Designed without technical limits, time bombs or other "gotchas", the Personal Edition provides all the power of the Oracle Database at a very attractive price point. With its ability to handle virtually any type or size of data (from gigabytes of transactions to terabytes of XML data, the Personal Edition takes you a significant step towards mastery of the Oracle environment.

This cost **$460** which is insane IMO but is this option ONLY for testing/developing with?  Meaning I couldn't actually use it on a site?

Any help with clarifying that or other tips appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's the [Oracle Express Edition](http://www.oracle.com/technology/xe/index.html) which is free.

Comment: We use this for developer laptops since we're locked into Oracle at the moment, would definitely recommend it as the easiest to install/configure as well.

Comment: sounds good, thanks!  Is this the real deal as to what I would be working with if I spent a lot of $$ for a production version?

Comment: It has the following limitations:  a single database instance, it will only use one CPU, and it's limited to 4GB of data.  Keep in mind that for most hobbyists, 4G of data is far more than they need, especially since developers usually just have a small subset of data in their development database.

Comment: Of course there will be missing features, but those are usually analysis, optimization and such. So it doesn't matter too much.

Answer (score 1):

"is this option ONLY for testing/developing with? Meaning I couldn't actually use it on a site? "

Yes you could use it in production but it is a single person licence, so it is only suited to quite unusual situations. Oh, and it is only available on Windows. Not sure why.

Answer (score 1):

The [rubric on Downloads page](http://www.oracle.com/technology/software/index.html) qualifies the Developer license with this statement:

> All software downloads are free, and
>   each comes with a Development License
>   that allows you to use full versions
>   of the products at no charge while
>   developing and prototyping your
>   applications *(or for strictly
>   self-educational purposes)*. [emphasis mine]

So, if you just want to teach yourself Oracle the OTN license allows us to install any version of the database, even the enterprise one.  But if you want to use it for any purpose which might be construed as commercial then you need a license.

I don't think you can use the Personal Edition on a web site either, because I'm pretty sure it's a named user license.  As Tor Valamo says, the limited Express Edition is the only cheap Oracle option.